# Rails 3 :uniqueness option spitting out syntax error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, syntax-error

I'm trying to figure out why this uniqueness option keeps failing and have exhausted all the options.  Anybody have any idea why this might be erroring out in rspec?

Many thanks,

```
$ rspec spec
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.0.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:454:in `load': /Users/habitat/Documents/RoR/tut/app/models/user.rb:10: syntax error, unexpected tASSOC, expecting kEND (SyntaxError)
                    :uniqueness => { :case_sensitive => false }
                                  ^
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.0.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:454:in `load_file'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.0.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:596:in `new_constants_in'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.0.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:453:in `load_file'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.0.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:340:in `require_or_load'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.0.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:300:in `depend_on'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.0.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:216:in `require_dependency'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.0.3/lib/rails/engine.rb:138:in `eager_load!'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.0.3/lib/rails/engine.rb:137:in `each'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.0.3/lib/rails/engine.rb:137:in `eager_load!'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.0.3/lib/rails/engine.rb:135:in `each'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.0.3/lib/rails/engine.rb:135:in `eager_load!'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.0.3/lib/rails/application.rb:108:in `eager_load!'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.0.3/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:41
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.0.3/lib/rails/initializable.rb:25:in `instance_exec'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.0.3/lib/rails/initializable.rb:25:in `run'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.0.3/lib/rails/initializable.rb:50:in `run_initializers'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.0.3/lib/rails/initializable.rb:49:in `each'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.0.3/lib/rails/initializable.rb:49:in `run_initializers'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.0.3/lib/rails/application.rb:134:in `initialize!'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.0.3/lib/rails/application.rb:77:in `send'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.0.3/lib/rails/application.rb:77:in `method_missing'
    from /Users/habitat/Documents/RoR/tut/spec/../config/environment.rb:5
    from /Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `gem_original_require'
    from /Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `require'
    from /Users/habitat/Documents/RoR/tut/spec/spec_helper.rb:10
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/spork-0.8.4/lib/spork.rb:23:in `prefork'
    from /Users/habitat/Documents/RoR/tut/spec/spec_helper.rb:4
    from /Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `gem_original_require'
    from /Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `require'
    from /Users/habitat/Documents/RoR/tut/spec/controllers/pages_controller_spec.rb:1
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rspec-core-2.1.0/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:334:in `load'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rspec-core-2.1.0/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:334:in `load_spec_files'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rspec-core-2.1.0/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:334:in `map'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rspec-core-2.1.0/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:334:in `load_spec_files'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rspec-core-2.1.0/lib/rspec/core/command_line.rb:18:in `run'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rspec-core-2.1.0/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:55:in `run_in_process'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rspec-core-2.1.0/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:46:in `run'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rspec-core-2.1.0/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:10:in `autorun'
    from /usr/bin/rspec:19
```

Here is the user.rb code which it looks like this issue is stemming from..

```
 class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name, :email

  email_regex = /\A[\w+\-.]+@[a-z\d\-.]+\.[a-z]+\z/i

  validates :name,  :presence => true,
                    :length   => { :maximum => 50 }
  validates :email, :presence => true,
                    :format   => { :with => email_regex }
                    :uniqueness => { :case_sensitive => false }
end
```

Comment: Please post your code, not just the error.

Comment: Please look above for the user.rb code. My apologies

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you certain your syntax looks like this `validates :name, :uniqueness => { :case_sensitive => false }` ? Did you maybe forget the ',' ? Or use something other than symbols ?

---

(edit corresponding to code posting)

You need a comma between the validators, like so

```
validates :email, :presence => true,
                :format   => { :with => email_regex }, # notice the comma after the hash
                :uniqueness => { :case_sensitive => false }
```

Comment: Thank you so much.  This seems to have fixed it :).